# PHPUnit Skeleton Generator

Tags: netbeans, phpunit

I use the latest Netbeans and try to use the phpunit test generation. it works fine for a class that doesn't extend another class, but fails to create the test for class that extends. i don't get any error in the IDE besides that it fails to generate it.

Comment: it doesn't work also from the command line (i got no error). i tried without extending the class and with and the results are:

/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/phpunit-skelgen --test -- "Acme\DemoBundle\Utils\FileHandle" FileHandle.php 
PHPUnit Skeleton Generator 1.2.1 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Wrote skeleton for "Acme\DemoBundle\Utils\FileHandleTest" to "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/calc/src/Acme/DemoBundle/Utils/FileHandleTest.php".

/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin/phpunit-skelgen --test -- "Acme\DemoBundle\Utils\PlusOperation" PlusOperation.php 
PHPUnit Skeleton Generator

Comment: maybe i need to configure the bootstrap?